# How to add employee to project by employee id

Tags: c#, console-application

These are my 3 lists

```
    public List<Project> _project { get; set; } = new List<Project>();
    public List<Employee> _employee { get; set; } = new List<Employee>();
    public List<Role> _role { get; set; } = new List<Role>();
```

List Project has

```
    public Project(int pId, string pName, int pStartDate, int pEndDate)
    {
        PId = pId;
        PName = pName;
        PStartDate = pStartDate;
        PEndDate = pEndDate;
    }
```

And List Employee has

```
    public Employee(int eId, string eFirstName, string eLastName, string eEmail, int eMobile, string eAddress, int eRoleId)
    {
        EId = eId;
        EFirstName = eFirstName;
        ELastName = eLastName;
        EEmail = eEmail;
        ERoleId = eRoleId;
    }
```

I want to add employee to Project List. Like if i enter project id then it ask me to enter employee id and after entering empId i able to add the whole detail of employee to that project list on specific project id.

Comment: Shouldn't your `Project` class have a property similat to `List<Employee> AssignedEmployees { get; set; }`?

Comment: Either its me or the question is a bit vague. Since you are new, you might be mixing some concepts. List is a data structure, for the purpose of this conversation you can imagine it like array. And here you have 3 "arrays", that are in no way connected. Neither of 3 "knows" about each other. You cannot add a "Foo" to a list of "Bars" if they aren't in some inheritance relationship.

Comment: no, i dont have any Project class have a property similat to List<Employee> AssignedEmployees { get; set; }

Comment: Suspiciously similar code to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70460070/how-to-add-role-id-element-of-role-list-to-employee-list if this is a home work question then please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 0):

you need a property of Employee in Project or List of Employee in Project Class and when you create a new object of Project You can add Employee to it by Create object od Employee and add to list

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).