# How to add role_Id element of role List to employee List?

Tags: c#

I am new to c#

I have an Employee List

```
 public List<Employee> _EmployeeVariable { get; set; } = new List<Employee>();
```

And employee list contains

```
 public Employee(string id, string firstname, string lastname,
      string email, string address, string roleid)
 {
      EID = id;
      EFName = firstname;
      ELName = lastname;
      EEmail = email;
      EAdress = adress;
      ERoleid = roleid;
 }
```

And I have a Role list

```
 public List<Role> _roleVariable { get; set; } = new List<Role>();
```

And Role list contains

```
 public Role(string id, string name)
 {
      RId = id;
      RName = name;
 }
```

I want that 'roleid' in 'employeelist' to be matched with 'roleid' in 'rolelist'.

If I entered 'roleid' in 'employeelist' as 1 so it matches with 'roleid' 1 in 'rolelist' with all detail in 'rolelist'.

Comment: Why doesn't the `Emlpoyee` have a `Role` property?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Either you need to pass the correct role id to the employee class or are you using Entity Framework and want to know why these aren't being set automatically?

Comment: employee have a roleid property, @fubo

Answer (score 1):

The below code will help you to match RoleId with employee RoleId and get details of it.

```
var finalData = (from emp in _EmployeeVariable
                      join role in _roleVariable on emp.ERoleid equals role.RId
                      select new {
                          EID = emp.EID,
                          EFName = emp.EFName,
                          ELName = emp.ELName,
                          EEmail = emp.EEmail,
                          EAdress = emp.EAdress,
                          ERoleid = role.RId,
                          ERoleName = role.RName
                      }).ToList();
```

Comment: where should i add this code?? @Pravin